# Expandable List Adapter - NPE debugging

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm working on implementing an ExpandableListView in my app, and I've run into a Null Pointer that I can't figure out. Implementing the expandable list has been tricky for me so I'm hoping someone with a bit more experience than me can see my error. The log is saying that the NPE is caused by line 55 in my Activity. For reference, that's the line that calls `listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);` Here's my Activity:

```
public class SearchResultsActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private static final String TAG = SearchResultsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ExpandableListView listView;
    private SearchItemAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<SearchItem> searchItems;
    private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_results);

        //define listivew and data model
        listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        searchItems = new ArrayList<SearchItem>();
        listAdapter = new SearchItemAdapter(this, searchItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_results, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // handle search intent

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

            volleySearch(query);
        }
    }

    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONArray response) {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject searchObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);

                SearchItem searchItem = new SearchItem();
                searchItem.setId(searchObj.getInt("id"));

                // product
                searchItem.setProduct(searchObj.getString("product"));

                //image
                searchItem.setItemImg(searchObj.getString("img"));

                //id
                searchItem.setId(searchObj.getInt("id"));

                //upc
                searchItem.setUpc(searchObj.getInt("upc"));

                // inventory_items
                JSONArray array = searchObj.getJSONArray("inventory_item");

                for (int k = 0; k < array.length(); k++ ) {
                    JSONObject invItem = (JSONObject) array.get(k);
                    InventoryItem item = new InventoryItem();

                    item.setId(invItem.getInt("id"));

                    item.setStoreName(invItem.getString("name"));

                    inventoryItems.add(item);
                }

                searchItems.add(searchItem);

            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

`volleySearch` just makes a Volley request and then calls `parseJsonFeed`.

Here's my Adapter:

```
public class SearchItemAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {  
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    private List<SearchItem> searchItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public SearchItemAdapter(Context context, List<SearchItem> searchItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.searchItems = searchItems;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.searchItems.get(groupPosition).getInventoryItems().get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.searchItems.get(groupPosition).getInventoryItems()
                .size();
    }

    @Override public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inventory_item, null);
        }

        TextView storeName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.store_name);

        storeName.setText(item.getStoreName());
        return convertView;


    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SearchItem item = (SearchItem) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_item, null);
        }

        TextView product = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.product);
        product.setText(item.getProduct());

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.searchItems.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.searchItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }


}
```

Finally my data objects:
`SearchItem`

```
public class SearchItem {
    private int id;
    private int upc;
    private String product;
    private String itemImg;
    private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems;

    public SearchItem() {
    }

    public SearchItem(int id, int upc, String product, String itemImg) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.product = product;
        this.itemImg = itemImg;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUpc() {
        return upc;
    }

    public void setUpc(int upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
    }

    public String getItemImg() {
        return itemImg;
    }

    public void setItemImg(String itemImg) {
        this.itemImg = itemImg;
    }

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public List<InventoryItem> getInventoryItems() {
        return inventoryItems;
    }

    public void setInventoryItems(List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems) {
        this.inventoryItems = inventoryItems;
    }
}
```

`InventoryItem`

```
public class InventoryItem {
    private int id;
    private int upc;
    private String vendorImage;
    private String storeName;
    private String price;

    public InventoryItem() {
    }

    public InventoryItem(int id, int upc, String storeName, String vendorImage, String price) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.upc = upc;
        this.vendorImage = vendorImage;
        this.storeName = storeName;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getUpc() {
        return upc;
    }

    public void setUpc(int upc) {
        this.upc = upc;
    }

    public String getVendorImage() {
        return vendorImage;
    }

    public void setVendorImage(String vendorImage) {
        this.vendorImage = vendorImage;
    }

    public String getStoreName() {
        return storeName;
    }

    public void setStoreName(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help or feedback on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Uses the function [getExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html#getExpandableListView()) from ExpandableListActivity

```
listView = getExpandableListView();
```